# Ruby тестирование query object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Пытаюсь тестировать query object.

Контроллер выглядит так:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_movie, except: [:index]

def index  
  @movies = FindMovies.new(Movie.all).call(movie_params)
end

private

def movie_params
  params.permit(:recommendation, :page, :current_user)
  params.merge!(current_user: current_user)
end
```

Сам query object:

```
class FindMovies
attr_accessor :initial_scope

def initialize(initial_scope)
  @initial_scope = initial_scope  
end

def call(params)
  scoped = @initial_scope
  if params[:recommendation] == 'recommended'
  scoped = recommended(scoped, params[:current_user])
elsif params[:recommendation] == 'not recommended'
  scoped = not_recommended(scoped, params[:current_user])
end
scoped = paginate(scoped, params[:page])
[scoped, params[:recommendation] || 'all']
end

private

def recommended(scoped, current_user)
  Movie.where(id: current_user.votes.where(value: 1).pluck(:movie_id))
end

def not_recommended(scoped, current_user)
  Movie.where(id: current_user.votes.where(value: -1).pluck(:movie_id))
end

def paginate(scoped, page)
  scoped.order(:created_at).page(page).per(10)
end
end
```

Тест:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Query tests' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:movie) { create(:movie) }
  let(:another_movie) { create(:movie, title: 'Gladiator', tmdb_id: 98) }
  let(:vote) { create(:vote, user_id: user.id, movie_id: movie.id) }
  let(:another_vote) { create(:vote, user_id: user.id, movie_id: another_movie.id, value: -1) }

context 'find move' do
  it 'returns all' do
    movies = FindMovies.new(Movie.all).call({ current_user: user })
    expect(movies.count).to eq(2)
    puts user.inspect
    expect(movies[1]).to eq('all')
  end

  it 'returns recommended' do
    movies = FindMovies.new(Movie.all).call({ current_user: user, recommendation: 'recommended' })
    puts user.inspect
    expect(movies[1]).to eq('recommended')
  end

  it 'returns not recommended' do
    movies = FindMovies.new(Movie.all).call({ current_user: user, recommendation: 'not recommended' })
    puts user.inspect
    expect(movies[1]).to eq('not recommended')
  end
end
end
```

По какой причине в каждом тесте user создается заново? Когда он должен создаваться один раз в let, а далее просто присваиватся параметру current_user?

Answer (score 1):

## Изоляции ради

Из [документации к `let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) (выделил жирным важную часть):

> Use `let` to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example **but not across examples**.

> Используйте `let`, чтобы определить мемоизующий метод-хелпер. Возвращаемое значение будет кэшировано для вызовов в пределах примера, **но не для разных примеров**.

Зачем?

RSpec, если только его не просят явно, старается максимально изолировать исполнение отдельных примеров, чтобы они минимально влияли друг на друга и оставались предсказуемыми при выполнении в любом порядке и любым подмножеством.

Поскольку вы в каждом примере потенциально можете изменить объект, который возвращается `let`-методом, с этой целью безопаснее этот объект пересоздавать для каждого примера.

*См. также [релевантный пункт Better Specs](http://www.betterspecs.org/ru/#let).*

---

Если вам действительно очень нужно, чтобы объект в нескольких примерах был одним и тем же, используйте [хук `before(:all)`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before(:all)-block-in-example-group) и переменные экземпляров (instance variables) а-ля `@thing`:

```
require "rspec/expectations"

class Thing
  def widgets
    @widgets ||= []
  end
end

describe Thing do
  before(:all) do
    @thing = Thing.new
  end

  describe "initialized in before(:all)" do
    it "has 0 widgets" do
      @thing.should have(0).widgets
    end

    it "can get accept new widgets" do
      @thing.widgets << Object.new
    end

    it "shares state across examples" do
      @thing.should have(1).widgets
    end
  end
end
```